# Model in Django 1.9. TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'verbose_name'

Tags: python, django

I have Python 3.5 and Django 1.9
try to do the next

```
class Question(models.Model):
def __init__(self, *args, question_text=None, pub_date=None, **kwargs):
    self.question_text = question_text
    self.pub_date = pub_date
question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Question")
pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date_published', verbose_name="Date")

def __str__(self):
    return self.question_text

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.question_text

class Meta:
    verbose_name = "Question"
```

But got an error

> File "/home/donotyou/PycharmProjects/djangobook/polls/models.py",
>   line 15, in Question
>       pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date_published', verbose_name="Date") TypeError: **init**() got multiple values for
>   argument 'verbose_name'

Please help

Comment: What for do you use overridden ```__init__()```?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to override `__init__` in Django. Django is doing everything for you, you just need to define your models and you are fine.

But the error you are getting because `pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date_published', verbose_name="Date")` here you are setting `verbose_name` twice, because the first argument of django `Field` is `verbose_name` and after that you setting the same `verbose_name` making two same arguments passing to class.

So basically you need to do is:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Question")
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date_published')  # or pub_date = models.DateTimeField("Date")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question_text

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Question"
```

**NOTE**: In most cases it's more readable to passing `verbose_name` as a first argument without any `verbose_name=` except relational fields.
From [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#verbose-field-names):

> Each field type, except for `ForeignKey`, `ManyToManyField` and `OneToOneField`, takes an optional first positional argument – a verbose name. If the verbose name isn’t given, Django will automatically create it using the field’s attribute name, converting underscores to spaces.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should not override `__init__()` here (as @vishes_shell supposed too). Instead of this, if you want to made some customization of instances initialization, you can add classmethod `create` to the model. Here is documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/instances/#creating-objects